# Adding to ArrayList in Java

Tags: java

I am new in Java development and I tried this program:

```
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0;i<ProductNumber;i++)
    {
       myList.add( mProducts[i].Name);
    }
    mProducts[1].Name = "Hello";
```

When I made `println` to show **myList** content:

**Expected**

> "A"
>   "B"
>   "C"

**Current**

```
>"A"  
>"Hello"  
>"C"
```

Can anybody tell me what is going on?

This is the code that I made:

```
    public class xmlParsing 
    {   
    private final static String XML_FILE_NAME = "Configuration.xml";
    private final static String PRODUCT_NODE = "product";
    private final static String TASK_NODE = "task";
    private final static String NAME_ITEM = "name";
    private final static String DURATION_ITEM = "duration";
    private final static String RATE_ITEM = "rate";

    private static int ProductNumber = 0;
    private static int TaskNumber = 0;
    private static Product mProducts[] = new Product[Product.MAX_PRODUCT_NUMBER];

    public xmlParsing()
    {
    }

    public void parseXML ()
    {
        Product[] Products = new Product[Product.MAX_PRODUCT_NUMBER];
        try 
        {
            File xmlFile = new File(XML_FILE_NAME);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList productsNode = doc.getElementsByTagName(PRODUCT_NODE);
            ProductNumber = productsNode.getLength();
            Product mproduct = new Product();
            Task mtask = new Task();
            for (int i = 0; i < productsNode.getLength(); i++) 
            {
                Node productNode = productsNode.item(i);
                if (productNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
                {
                    Element element1 = (Element) productNode;
                    mproduct.Name = getValue(NAME_ITEM, element1);
                    NodeList tasksNode = element1.getElementsByTagName(TASK_NODE);
                    TaskNumber = tasksNode.getLength();
                    Task[] Tasks = new Task[Task.MAX_TASKS_NUMBER];
                    for (int j = 0; j < tasksNode.getLength(); j++) 
                    {
                        Node taskNode = tasksNode.item(j);
                        if (taskNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
                        {
                            Element element2 = (Element) taskNode;
                            mtask.Name = getValue(NAME_ITEM, element2);
                    mtask.Duration = Double.parseDouble(getValue(DURATION_ITEM, element2));
                            mtask.Rate = Double.parseDouble(getValue(RATE_ITEM, element2));
                            Tasks[j] = new Task(mtask);
                        } 
                    }
                    mproduct.Tasks = Tasks;
                    Products[i] = new Product(mproduct);
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        mProducts = Products;
    }

    private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) 
    {
        NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
        Node node = (Node) nodes.item(0);
        return node.getNodeValue();
    }

    public static List<String> getProdcutNames() 
    {
       String ps[] = new String[ProductNumber];
       List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
       for(int i = 0;i<ProductNumber;i++)
       {
           ps[i] =  mProducts[i].Name;
           myList.add(new String(mProducts[i].Name));
       }
        mProducts[2].Name = "Hello";
       return myList;
    }

    public int getProductNumber()
    {
        return ProductNumber;
    }

    public int getTasktNumber()
    {
        return TaskNumber;
    }
    }

    public class Task {
    public static final int MAX_TASKS_NUMBER = 100;
    public String Name;
    public double Duration;
    public double Rate;

    public Task(){
        Name = "";
        Duration = 0;
        Rate = 0;
    }

    public Task(Task t){
        Name = t.Name;
        Duration = t.Duration;
        Rate = t.Rate;
    }

    }

    public class Product {
    public static final int MAX_PRODUCT_NUMBER = 200;
    public String Name;
    public Task[] Tasks;

    public Product(){
        Name = "";
        Tasks = null;
    }

    public Product(Product p){
        Name = p.Name;
        Tasks = p.Tasks;
    } 
    }


    public class Production {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        xmlParsing parser = new xmlParsing();
        parser.parseXML();
        for(int i=0;i<parser.getProductNumber();i++)
            System.out.println(parser.getProdcutNames().get(i));

    }
    }
```

The xml file is

```
    <product>
    <name>1510</name>
    <task>
        <name>DECOUPAGE PRESSE 250T</name>
        <duration>1</duration>
        <rate>144</rate>
    </task>
    <task>
        <name>LAMINAGE PARBOLIQUE 1</name>
        <duration>0</duration>
        <rate>72.1</rate>
    </task>
     </product>
    <product>
    <name>2020</name>
    <task>
        <name>DECOUPAGE PRESSE 250T</name>
        <duration>1</duration>
        <rate>144</rate>
    </task>
    <task>
        <name>LAMINAGE PARBOLIQUE 1</name>
        <duration>0</duration>
        <rate>72.1</rate>
    </task>
     </product>
```

Expected : 1510  2020
Current    1510 Hello

Comment: Can't replicate your behavior. Post a code sample might help.

Comment: I would guess that myProducts contains entries with Name values of "A", "Hello", and "C".

Comment: Are you printing mProducts instead?

Comment: With your actual code, the problem will **never** be reproduced since `String` instances are immutable. You must have a bug in your code or doing something else like shadowing a variable thus getting this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though `mProducts` and `myList` are referring to the same object, but in the code you gave, that can't happen.  Did you simplify the code, removing something like `mProducts = myList`?

Comment: or maybe `mList.Name` and `mProducts.Name` refer to the same object

Comment: @A.E.Drew: But Java strings are immutable.

Comment: @RichieHindle unless I'm mistaken, I see an assignment to a field in an object instance that is both in the array and the list? `String` references are not immutable...

Comment: @owlstead the references are not, but changing the references cannot affect the actual object.

Comment: @owlstead: `myList` is an array of strings, not an array of object instances.

Comment: @RichieHindle yeah, that is correct, but in that case the code is indeed FUBAR-ed, and the question/answer can take any direction...

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this, and it should serve the purpose

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0;i<ProductNumber;i++)
{
   myList.add( new String(mProducts[i].Name));
}
mProducts[1].Name = "Hello";
```

Comment: @user1955287 no matter what you try with these minor changes, the problem is somewhere else in your not-posted code.

Comment: @user1955287 - Not sure what you meant by "your-not-posted code". I made one small change if you look carefully at myList.add(new String(mProducts[i].Name)). In your code you are passing reference to List, which means object in myList and mProducts[i].Name will point to same object, this is the reason I changed it to new String(mProducts[i].Name)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting your complete code.  The problem is that you're calling `getProdcutNames()` (you have a typo in the name there, by the way) several times in `main()` - every time round the loop in `main` you call `getProdcutNames()` again:

```
for(int i=0;i<parser.getProductNumber();i++)
    System.out.println(parser.getProdcutNames().get(i));
```

So the first time you call `getProdcutNames()`, `mProducts` gets modified via the line `mProducts[2].Name = "Hello";`, and then when `getProdcutNames()` gets called again, you're copying from the modified version into `myList`.

The simplest fix, which also makes the code more efficient, is to only call `getProdcutNames()` once in `main()`:

```
List<String> names = parser.getProdcutNames();
for(int i = 0; i < names.size() ;i++)
    System.out.println(names.get(i));
```